# Intergration ios 6 and facebook

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

It is first time Im going to develop integration between out app on ios with facebook.

Now I understand that I can use simultaneously both Facebook's integration apis and Apple's integration apis.

Could you please advice me that in that case
In the same one Ios application, :

1.What should Facebook's intergration apis do.
 2.What should Apple's intergration apis do.

Thank you very much !

Doanh